# How to remove unneccessary spaces from table output in shell while still keeping columns aligned?

Tags: shell, text-formatting, output

Below command outputs a table of space delimited text, is there a tool to remove the unnecessary spacing here while still keeping the columns aligned?

```
$ sudo ss -ltpn
State      Recv-Q Send-Q                                                                       Local Address:Port                                                                                      Peer Address:Port    
LISTEN     0      32                                                                            10.218.108.1:53                                                                                                   *:*       
users:(("dnsmasq",pid=10242,fd=9))
LISTEN     0      128                                                                                      *:22                                                                                                   *:*       
users:(("sshd",pid=1111,fd=3))
LISTEN     0      32                                                                  fd42:9324:ab98:50fb::1:53                                                                                                  :::*       
users:(("dnsmasq",pid=10242,fd=13))
LISTEN     0      32                                                        fe80::c024:c5ff:fe68:999e%lxdbr0:53                                                                                                  :::*       
users:(("dnsmasq",pid=10242,fd=11))
LISTEN     0      128                                                                                     :::22                                                                                                  :::*
```

Comment: How do you define "unnecessary"? Do you still need the columns to be aligned, or is it enough to just replace all multiple spaces with a tab character so that you can parse it easily even if it doesn't look great when printed?

Comment: Thanks, yes, still keeping columns aligned, updating question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that `ss` can do this for you if you just pipe the output or redirect it to a file. For example, on my system, without piping, I get this:

```
$ sudo ss -ltpn 
State               Recv-Q              Send-Q                           Local Address:Port                            Peer Address:Port             Process                                                                
LISTEN              0                   128                                    0.0.0.0:53939                                0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("spotify",pid=4152748,fd=115))                                
LISTEN              0                   10                                     0.0.0.0:57621                                0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("spotify",pid=4152748,fd=96))                                 
LISTEN              0                   128                                    0.0.0.0:22                                   0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("sshd",pid=822,fd=3))                                         
LISTEN              0                   128                                  127.0.0.1:10391                                0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("Enpass",pid=2193055,fd=38))                                  
LISTEN              0                   5                                    127.0.0.1:631                                  0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("cupsd",pid=818,fd=8))                                        
LISTEN              0                   5                                    127.0.0.1:9292                                 0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("emacs",pid=178419,fd=13))                                    
LISTEN              0                   4096                                   0.0.0.0:111                                  0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("rpcbind",pid=314,fd=4),("systemd",pid=1,fd=106))             
LISTEN              0                   5                                    127.0.0.1:34512                                0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("purevpnd",pid=839,fd=6))                                     
LISTEN              0                   128                                       [::]:22                                      [::]:*                 users:(("sshd",pid=822,fd=4))                                         
LISTEN              0                   5                                        [::1]:631                                     [::]:*                 users:(("cupsd",pid=818,fd=7))                                        
LISTEN              0                   4096                                      [::]:111                                     [::]:*                 users:(("rpcbind",pid=314,fd=6),("systemd",pid=1,fd=128))
```

If I simply pipe to `cat`, however, I get:

```
$ sudo ss -ltpn | cat
State  Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port  Peer Address:PortProcess                                                   
LISTEN 0      128          0.0.0.0:53939      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("spotify",pid=4152748,fd=115))                   
LISTEN 0      10           0.0.0.0:57621      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("spotify",pid=4152748,fd=96))                    
LISTEN 0      128          0.0.0.0:22         0.0.0.0:*    users:(("sshd",pid=822,fd=3))                            
LISTEN 0      128        127.0.0.1:10391      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("Enpass",pid=2193055,fd=38))                     
LISTEN 0      5          127.0.0.1:631        0.0.0.0:*    users:(("cupsd",pid=818,fd=8))                           
LISTEN 0      5          127.0.0.1:9292       0.0.0.0:*    users:(("emacs",pid=178419,fd=13))                       
LISTEN 0      4096         0.0.0.0:111        0.0.0.0:*    users:(("rpcbind",pid=314,fd=4),("systemd",pid=1,fd=106))
LISTEN 0      5          127.0.0.1:34512      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("purevpnd",pid=839,fd=6))                        
LISTEN 0      128             [::]:22            [::]:*    users:(("sshd",pid=822,fd=4))                            
LISTEN 0      5              [::1]:631           [::]:*    users:(("cupsd",pid=818,fd=7))                           
LISTEN 0      4096            [::]:111           [::]:*    users:(("rpcbind",pid=314,fd=6),("systemd",pid=1,fd=128))
```

I also get the same output if I just redirect to a file: `sudo ss -ltpn > file`.

---

For a more general solution, you can use `column`. For example, given this input file:

```
$ cat file
State          Recv-Q         Send-Q                   Local Address:Port                    Peer Address:Port         Process                                                            
LISTEN         0              128                            0.0.0.0:53939                        0.0.0.0:*             users:(("spotify",pid=4152748,fd=115))                            
LISTEN         0              10                             0.0.0.0:57621                        0.0.0.0:*             users:(("spotify",pid=4152748,fd=96))                             
LISTEN         0              128                            0.0.0.0:22                           0.0.0.0:*             users:(("sshd",pid=822,fd=3))                                     
LISTEN         0              128                          127.0.0.1:10391                        0.0.0.0:*             users:(("Enpass",pid=2193055,fd=38))                              
LISTEN         0              5                            127.0.0.1:631                          0.0.0.0:*             users:(("cupsd",pid=818,fd=8))                                    
LISTEN         0              5                            127.0.0.1:9292                         0.0.0.0:*             users:(("emacs",pid=178419,fd=13))                                
LISTEN         0              4096                           0.0.0.0:111                          0.0.0.0:*             users:(("rpcbind",pid=314,fd=4),("systemd",pid=1,fd=106))         
LISTEN         0              5                            127.0.0.1:34512                        0.0.0.0:*             users:(("purevpnd",pid=839,fd=6))                                 
LISTEN         0              128                               [::]:22                              [::]:*             users:(("sshd",pid=822,fd=4))                                     
LISTEN         0              5                                [::1]:631                             [::]:*             users:(("cupsd",pid=818,fd=7))                                    
LISTEN         0              4096                              [::]:111                             [::]:*             users:(("rpcbind",pid=314,fd=6),("systemd",pid=1,fd=128))
```

I can pass it through `column -t` to pretty print it:

```
$ column -t -N"State,Recv-Q,Send-Q,Local Address:Port,Peer Address:Port,Process" <(tail -n +2 file)
State   Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address:Port  Peer Address:Port  Process
LISTEN  0       128     0.0.0.0:53939       0.0.0.0:*          users:(("spotify",pid=4152748,fd=115))
LISTEN  0       10      0.0.0.0:57621       0.0.0.0:*          users:(("spotify",pid=4152748,fd=96))
LISTEN  0       128     0.0.0.0:22          0.0.0.0:*          users:(("sshd",pid=822,fd=3))
LISTEN  0       128     127.0.0.1:10391     0.0.0.0:*          users:(("Enpass",pid=2193055,fd=38))
LISTEN  0       5       127.0.0.1:631       0.0.0.0:*          users:(("cupsd",pid=818,fd=8))
LISTEN  0       5       127.0.0.1:9292      0.0.0.0:*          users:(("emacs",pid=178419,fd=13))
LISTEN  0       4096    0.0.0.0:111         0.0.0.0:*          users:(("rpcbind",pid=314,fd=4),("systemd",pid=1,fd=106))
LISTEN  0       5       127.0.0.1:34512     0.0.0.0:*          users:(("purevpnd",pid=839,fd=6))
LISTEN  0       128     [::]:22             [::]:*             users:(("sshd",pid=822,fd=4))
LISTEN  0       5       [::1]:631           [::]:*             users:(("cupsd",pid=818,fd=7))
LISTEN  0       4096    [::]:111            [::]:*             users:(("rpcbind",pid=314,fd=6),("systemd",pid=1,fd=128))
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried your suggesting on piping to `cat` and also a file and the output was mangled a bit, spacing wasn't correctly keeping the columns aligned. But then tried on my local machine and it works great. So something is up with the different environments. Marked as correct answer though, thanks!

Comment: @ElijahLynn the way it is printed depends on the size of your terminal (or, I am assuming, the value of the `$COLUMNS` variable if you're not using a GUI terminal emulator). I suspect that if you just resize your terminal, you'll see better results. Alternatively, try the `column` solution from the updated answer.

Comment: Ahh, my local has a newer version of `ss` that just uses the right amount of spaces so maybe that was a bug/improvement in `ss` that was fixed. Both shells were the same size. Using your suggestion, this variation works great `ss -lptn | column -t` (just piping to `column -t`.

Comment: @ElijahLynn that one, at least on my system, breaks the headers. The `Local Address:Port` column becomes `Local` and the `Peer` is empty. That's why I used the `N` option to give the names of the columns and `tail -n+2` to pass everything except the first line to `column`. Are you _sure_ that the simple `ss -lptn | column -t` works for you and doesn't mangle the headers?

Comment: Interesting, just tested on my local too (latest everything, Arch) and works nicely. I just updated my question here with the output from the server (same effect as local) > https://serverfault.com/questions/1016031/how-can-a-server-accept-incoming-traffic-to-port-443-if-it-isnt-listed-in-netst

Comment: Oh that is right, my local doesn't have this issue with `ss` so the formatting is already correct. I just copied the remote server output to a local file and `cat file | column -t` and yup, it is broken!

Comment: @ElijahLynn ah, OK. Makes more sense. Use the `column` with the names as I have in the answer and you should be fine though.

Comment: @ElijahLynn the output you added to your SF question is misaligned, just as I described. You have a column named `Local`, a column named `Address:Port`, another named `Peer` and an empty one named `Address:Port` again. What you should have (and what you get if you use my command) is `Local Address:Port`, `Peer Address:Port` and `Process`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ss -ltpn | awk '{ gsub("\\s{2,}"," "); print; }'
State Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port Peer Address:Port Process 
LISTEN 0 128 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* 
LISTEN 0 5 127.0.0.1:631 0.0.0.0:* 
LISTEN 0 100 127.0.0.1:25 0.0.0.0:* 
LISTEN 0 50 *:1716 *:* users:(("kdeconnectd",pid=2952,fd=15)) 
LISTEN 0 50 *:1717 *:* 
LISTEN 0 128 [::]:22 [::]:* 
LISTEN 0 5 [::1]:631 [::]:* 
LISTEN 0 100 [::1]:25 [::]:*
```

Comment: That's a convoluted and non-portable way to write: `ss -ltpn | tr -s '[:space:]'`